# ruby on rails read decoded xml string from post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, base64

This is on rails 3/4 (two different test environments).   I have a client that base64 encodes XML in a POST.  I can decode the string, which looks like well-formed XML.  How do I turn that into XML that rails can actually recognize?  Meaning, I don't need all the information in the XML, only a few pieces of content contained in a few of the nodes.

EX: original XML

```
<xml....>
<node1>content</node1>
<node2>content2</node2>
<node3>content3</node3>
</xml>
```

.....
base64 encoded and posted in a query string

url....?name=base64(xml)

i can then pull the params

```
myvariable = Base64.decode64(params[:name])
```

at this point, myvariable is just a long string.  I'd rather not parse using a string search because the string could be pretty long.

.....

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can probably map it to a ruby object using something like [Happy Mapper](https://github.com/dam5s/happymapper).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails, which it looks like you are, the rails team have already patched the Hash object to allow you to do this with `Hash.from_xml(xml_string)`.

```
>   a = "<xml><node1>content</node1><node2>content2</node2><node3>content3</node3></xml>"
 => "<xml><node1>content</node1><node2>content2</node2><node3>content3</node3></xml>" 
> hash = Hash.from_xml(a)
 => {"xml"=>{"node1"=>"content", "node2"=>"content2", "node3"=>"content3"}}
```

You then have a plain old ruby object that you can interregate as you wish. Note that this will only work with well-formed XML (your example was missing close tags)